# Login System Not Working, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

First of all, this post is going to be long, thanks for helping tho.

Hello so I've been trying to create a login and register system on my CodeIgniter Application. So far it works great, I can create and fetch them(if not logged in) wherever I want them to be displayed, the problem that now comes to me is the restricting part.

For example I have an admin_controller to which I need to restrict the access. Rather than adding a code to any controller that needs the same configuration, I created a "MY_Controller" in the core folder, here is my code:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // Check Login
        /*if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }*/
    }
}

class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('menu');

        $pages_public /*$this->pages*/ = $this->menu->get_pages();

        // Brand/Logo
        $this->brand = 'My Website';

        // Banner
        $this->banner_heading = 'Welcome To Our Website';
        $this->banner_text = 'This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.';
        $this->banner_link = 'pages/show/our-team';
    }
}
```

and this is what I have on my admin_controller, so far nothing wrong:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends Admin_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $data['pages'] = $this->Page_model->get_list();

        // Load template
        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'pages/index', $data);
    }

    public function add(){
        // Field Rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject_id', 'Subject', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_published', 'Publish', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_featured', 'Feature', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('order', 'Order', 'integer');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $subject_options = array();
            $subject_options[0] = 'Select Page Category';

            $subject_list = $this->Pages_categories_model->get_list();

            foreach($subject_list as $subject){
                $subject_options[$subject->id] = $subject->name;
            }

            $data['subject_options'] = $subject_options;

            // Load template
            $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'pages/add', $data);
        } else {
            $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $this->input->post('title'));
            $slug = strtolower($slug);

            // Page Data
            $data = array(
                'title'         => $this->input->post('title'),
                'slug'          => $slug,
                'subject_id'    => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
                'body'          => $this->input->post('body'),
                'is_published'  => $this->input->post('is_published'),
                'is_featured'   => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
                'in_menu'       => $this->input->post('in_menu'),
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'order'         => $this->input->post('order')
            ); 

            // Insert Page
            $this->Page_model->add($data);

            // Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id'   => $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'          => 'page',
                'action'        => 'added',
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'message'       => 'A new page was added ('.$data["title"].')'
            );

            // Insert Activity
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            // Set Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page has been added');

            // Redirect
            redirect('admin/pages');
        }

    }

    public function edit($id){
        // Field Rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject_id', 'Subject', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_published', 'Publish', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_featured', 'Feature', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('order', 'Order', 'integer');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data['item'] = $this->Page_model->get($id);

            $subject_options = array();
            $subject_options[0] = 'Select Page Category';

            $subject_list = $this->Pages_categories_model->get_list();

            foreach($this->Pages_categories_model->get_list() as $subject){
                $subject_options[$subject->id] = $subject->name;
            }

            $data['subject_options'] = $subject_options;

            // Load template
            $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'pages/edit', $data);
        } else {
            $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $this->input->post('title'));
            $slug = strtolower($slug);

            // Page Data
            $data = array(
                'title'         => $this->input->post('title'),
                'slug'          => $slug,
                'subject_id'    => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
                'body'          => $this->input->post('body'),
                'is_published'  => $this->input->post('is_published'),
                'is_featured'   => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
                'in_menu'       => $this->input->post('in_menu'),
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'order'         => $this->input->post('order')
            ); 

            // Update Page
            $this->Page_model->update($id, $data);

            // Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id'   => $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'          => 'page',
                'action'        => 'updated',
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'message'       => 'A page was updated ('.$data["title"].')'
            );

            // Insert Activity
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            // Set Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page has been updated');

            // Redirect
            redirect('admin/pages');

        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $title = $this->Page_model->get($id)->title;

        // Delete Page
        $this->Page_model->delete($id);

        // Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id'   => $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'          => 'page',
                'action'        => 'deleted',
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'message'       => 'A page was deleted'
            );

            // Insert Activity
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            // Set Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page has been deleted');

            // Redirect
            redirect('admin/pages');
    }
}
```

the problem comes from the controller users_controller. I already created an account with some data and that data should at least allow me to have access to the admin_controller which it does not, instead it redirects me to the admin/login form.

I would like to say that for some reason when I tried to add a page, I get an error message saying that user_id cannot be null, but as I'm "supposed" to be logged in that error should not appear. Any knows how to fix it?

Error Message

> Error Number: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null INSERT INTO 'pages'
>   ('title', 'slug', 'subject_id', 'body', 'is_published', 'is_featured',
>   'in_menu', 'user_id', 'order') VALUES ('Page One', 'page-one', '1', '
>   thrhjtyjrjrj ', '1', '0', '1', NULL, '1')
>
> Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/application/models/page_model.php Line
>   Number: 20

User_Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        // Check Login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_list();
        // Load template
        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'users/index', $data);
    }

    public function add(){
        // Check Login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','trim|required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','trim|required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|min_length[7]|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]|matches[password2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm Password','trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[password2]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            // Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin','default','users/add');
        } else {
            // Create Page Data Array
            $data = array(
                'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'     => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                'username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password'      => md5($this->input->post('password'))
            );   

            // Add User
            $this->User_model->add($data);

            //Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id'   =>  $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'          => 'user',
                'action'        => 'added',
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'message'       => 'A new user was added ('.$data["username"].')'
            ); 

            // Add Activity  
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User has been added');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('admin/users');
        }
    }

    public function edit($id){
        // Check Login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','trim|required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','trim|required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|min_length[7]|valid_email');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            // Get Current Subject
            $data['item'] = $this->User_model->get($id);
            //Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin','default','users/edit', $data);
        } else {
            // Create User Data Array
            $data = array(
                'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'     => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                'username'      => $this->input->post('username')
            );   

            // Update User
            $this->User_model->update($id, $data);

            // Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id'   =>  $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'          => 'user',
                'action'        => 'updated',
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'message'       => 'A user was updated ('.$data["username"].')'
            ); 

            // Add Activity  
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            //Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User has been updated');

            //Redirect to Users
            redirect('admin/users');
        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        // Check Login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        // Get Username
        $username = $this->User_model->get($id)->username;

        // Delete User
        $this->User_model->delete($id);

        // Activity Array
        $data = array(
            'resource_id'   =>  $this->db->insert_id(),
            'type'          => 'user',
            'action'        => 'deleted',
            'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'message'       => 'A user was deleted'
        ); 

        // Add Activity  
        $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        // Create Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User has been deleted');

        // Redirect to Subjects
        redirect('admin/users');
    }

    public function login(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            //Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin','login','users/login');
        } else {
           // Get Post Data
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $enc_password = md5($password);

            $user_id = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);

            if($user_id){
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'username'  => $username,
                    'logged_in' => true
                );

                // Set Session Data
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

                // Create Message
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');

                // Redirect to pages
                redirect('admin');
            } else {
                // Create Error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Login');

                // Redirect to pages
                redirect('admin/users/login');
            }
        }
    }

        public function register(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','trim|required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','trim|required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|min_length[7]|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]|matches[password2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm Password','trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[password2]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            // Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin','login','users/register');
        } else {
            // Create Page Data Array
            $data = array(
                'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'     => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                'username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password'      => md5($this->input->post('password'))
            );   

            // Add User
            $this->User_model->add($data);

            //Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id'   =>  $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'          => 'user',
                'action'        => 'registered',
                'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                'message'       => 'A new user was registered ('.$data["username"].')'
            ); 

            // Add Activity  
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User has been registered');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('admin/users/login');
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        // Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged out');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Here is my user_model(in case you would like to check it):

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_MODEL{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'users';
    }

    public function get_list(){
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->row();
    }

    public function add($data){
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function update($id, $data){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return $query->row()->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the question here.  Your code looks fine. If you want to protect your admin controller than just uncomment your check login if statement... What am I missing?

Comment: I tried doing that, but if I uncomment it, not matter how many times I try to log in with the ALREADY created account, it keeps redirecting me to the login form. :/ ...

Comment: by keeps redirecting me I am assuming its not a redirect loop as in "this page has redirected you too many times" error on chrome. if that is not the case, and you login and get redirected back to your login page after hitting the admin controller I'm guessing your session isn't being properly set although I see it being set. I would suggest running a var_dump on `$this->session->logged_in` both before and after logging in where you have the uncommented section now to check the values. Also Duy might be correct, are you loading the session library before all this?

Comment: I updated my question because I realized it was not properly formatted. Yes I tried doing that, I have a function in the user_model called login but it does not work. Yes as you said, it gives me the "too many requests" Google error but the session library is loaded on my config file... I really don't know what my problem is. Thansk

Comment: Checking the login model and the `User_model` everything seems to be in order. I only see one redirect two redirects in the login function that doesn't under an circumstance redirect the user to the admin controller immediately... only after form submission does that potentially happen. So i'm not sure where your loop is coming from. I would clear your sessions, login, and `var_dump($this->session)` on the admin controller and see if it reports the data you set.

Comment: if it does, and logged_in is bool and TRUE (which it should be if your session data is getting set), i don't see why it would be redirecting you

Comment: I now get an 404 error and the routes are already configured

Comment: you are probably getting that error because youre on your admin controller page which has no index function (i'm assuming its not in the core directory)

Comment: what do you mean it has not index function? It has it :/ , the only controller which has not function index is the "MY_Controller"(in the core directory) that I use to extend the admin_controller.

Answer (score 1):

1/ You should write a private method for checking logged user like this

```
private function checkLogin()
{
     if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
}
```

2/ You must make sure that you loaded the library session.

Comment: I will put my model to show you what I have, if I do what you say, I have a function called login but still it does not work